What could be causing cookies not to work on IOS?
I built a little banner that appear at the top of the page until the user closes it. Once closed, it should not show again for 24 hours. I have tried to do so using cookies - when the user x's out the banner, a cookie called "close_mobile_banner" with the date as the value is stored for 24 hours. This is working on desktop, but not IOS (I haven't tried other OS's). When the user closes the banner on IOS, it appears again when the page is refreshed (should be hidden for 24 hours).
header.blade.php (this is a blade template - it's basically PHP with a few differences)
Note - I simplified the code a bit so it's easier to skim. This code is fully functional (just not on ios..)
...
@if (!isset($_COOKIE['close_mobile_banner']))
      @php
        $bg_color         = get_sub_field('background_color');
        $text_color       = get_sub_field('text_color');
        $copy             = get_sub_field('copy');
      @endphp

      <div class="mobile-banner" style="background-color: {{ $bg_color }}; color: {{ $text_color }}">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <p class="mobile-banner-copy">{{ $copy }}</p>
          <a href="{{ $google_play_link }}" class="android-image mobile-banner-image">
            <svg width="108" height="32" viewBox="0 0 108 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
          </a>
          <button class="mobile-banner-close" onclick="event.preventDefault();$(this).closest('.mobile-banner').removeClass('active'); setCookie('close_mobile_banner', new Date().toISOString(), 1)"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
  @endif
  ...

cookies.js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    const d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + ";" + expires + ";path=/";

    window.alert(getCookie(cname));
}
// debugging 
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}

This is a WordPress site, using Blade/Laravel, Advanced Custom Fields, and checking on an iPhone SE (Safari and Chrome).

Use your browser's developer tools. Look for errors, and also inspect the cookie payloads. Also, I personally recommend to do all of this in JS, not server-side, in order to better account for caching. To do that, always emit the HTML for the banner, and use JS to hide/show it.
